# I can't import "row ids" XML nodes into DataGridView in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, rowid

If I'm importing data such as this it will not work.

Debug also shows

"A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XMLDocument>
  <Books>
    <Book>
      <row id="0">
    <data_rate_in_as_string>0B</data_rate_in_as_string>
    <data_rate_out_as_string>0B</data_rate_out_as_string>
    <downloaded_as_string>956.6MB</downloaded_as_string>
    <elapsed_as_string>174d2h48m49s</elapsed_as_string>
      </row>
    </Book>
    <Book>
      <row id="1">
    <data_rate_in_as_string>0B</data_rate_in_as_string>
    <data_rate_out_as_string>0B</data_rate_out_as_string>
    <downloaded_as_string>956.6MB</downloaded_as_string>
    <elapsed_as_string>174d2h48m49s</elapsed_as_string>
      </row>
    </Book>
  </Books>
</XMLDocument>
```

However if I removed the row ids completely it will work and I can import my data.
I want to keep my row ids however and I also would like to add them to my datagridview too.

This is the project code as so far if it helps.

```
    Public Shared Function EmptyStringToNull(o As String) As Object
    Dim ret As Object = DBNull.Value
    Try
        If o.Trim.Length = 0 Then
            ret = DBNull.Value
        Else
            ret = o
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return ret
End Function

Private Sub ReadXMLFile()
    Dim xmlDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim root As XmlElement = Nothing
    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = Nothing
    Dim node As XmlNode = Nothing
    Dim xmlFile As String = ""
    Try
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        xmlFile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile)
        root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
        nodes = root.SelectNodes("//XMLDocument/Books/Book/") 'The XMLPath
        'nodes = root.SelectNodes("//result/data/row") 'The XMLPath
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Clear() 'Clear Grid
        For Each node In nodes
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(EmptyStringToNull(node("rowid").InnerText),
                                      EmptyStringToNull(node("data_rate_in_as_string").InnerText),
                                      EmptyStringToNull(node("data_rate_out_as_string").InnerText),
                                      EmptyStringToNull(node("downloaded_as_string").InnerText),
                                      EmptyStringToNull(node("elapsed_as_string").InnerText))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change relevant part of your code to this :

```
nodes = root.SelectNodes("//XMLDocument/Books/Book") 'The XMLPath
Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Clear() 'Clear Grid
For Each node In nodes
    Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(EmptyStringToNull(node("row").GetAttribute("id")),
                              EmptyStringToNull(node("row")("data_rate_in_as_string").InnerText),
                              EmptyStringToNull(node("row")("data_rate_out_as_string").InnerText),
                              EmptyStringToNull(node("row")("downloaded_as_string").InnerText),
                              EmptyStringToNull(node("row")("elapsed_as_string").InnerText))
Next
```

Summary of what has been fixed above :

1. your XPath shouldn't end with slash (`/`)
2. node name is "row" instead of "rowid", and you can use
   `.GetAttribute()` function to get attribute value of an `XmlNode`
3. the rest of elements you're trying to select are child of `<row>`
   element, hence you need to append `node("row")` before

Comment: I will let you know if this works however from looking at it I think it will.
Thankyou for the help and knowledge. This has helped me a great deal.

Comment: No luck and problem still persisting. A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Comment: At which line of code the exception was thrown? And check inner exception for more specific error message to know what exactly caused the exception.

Comment: It's not causing the application to close and so it's just throwing that exception in the debug list thing. How would i go about checking the inner exception by the way?

Comment: run your project in debug mode, then you can check inner exception in exception pop up > click view detail

Comment: I was able to find the problem and it appears to be with my XML file and I got that fixed.